# Get process executed by MONO on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, process, mono

I am using MONO to execute an application. Using ps command shows eihter processname MONO or CLI.
How can I get the name of the application executed by MONO ?

Example : mono myApp.exe

I want to know, if myApp.exe is currently excecuted. Finally I want to do this check programmatically.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You usually will run your program from a shell script and there you can use the -a flag to exec:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -a VisibleName mono program.exe
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but does not work for me. On Telnet connection #1 I used your proposal. On Telnet Connection #2 I do not see the VisibleName. I just see MONO in process list. What is going wrong ? Cheers

Comment: Hi, I got it. I need to use ps -ef to see the visible name. Now I need to check how my mono application can access the visibleName too. (this application shall check if my primary application is still running. If my primary application stopped execution I want to start it again automatically) Cheers

Comment: Hi, my Goal is to have a clean .NET/MONO solution. (no native DLLs and not piping PS -ef output) As .NET/MONO does not support to provide the visibleName, the initial solution is still an option. But again 100x thanks for your proposal. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses .NET/MONO functions (no need to invoke native DLLs nor piping Shell Output):

- List all processes.
- If a process Name contains MONO or CLI then read
  the commandline of that process
- The commandline shall contain all
  needed Information to identify your application

  ```
   public static int process_count(string application_name)
  {
      int rc = 0;
      string cmdline = "";

      Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

      foreach (Process p in processlist)
      {

          cmdline = "";

          //Console.WriteLine("PID : " + theprocess.Id + " " + theprocess.ProcessName);

          if (p.ProcessName.Contains("mono"))
          {
              Console.WriteLine("PID : " + p.Id + " " + p.ProcessName + " " + p.MainModule.FileName);
              cmdline = File.ReadAllText("/proc/" + p.Id.ToString() + "/cmdline");
              Console.WriteLine("CMDLINE : "+cmdline);
          }

          if (p.ProcessName.Contains("cli"))
          {
              Console.WriteLine("PID : " + p.Id + " " + p.ProcessName + " " + p.MainModule.FileName);
              cmdline = File.ReadAllText("/proc/" + p.Id.ToString() + "/cmdline");
              Console.WriteLine("CMDLINE : " + cmdline);
          }


          if (cmdline.Contains(application_name))
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Found existing process: {0} ID: {1}", p.ProcessName, p.Id);
              rc++;
          }
      }
      return (rc);
  }
  ```

How to do it manually:

- invoke ps -e to get all processes of MONO or CLI
- Look up the PID e.g. 2845
- Display command line : cat /proc/2845/cmdline

Note for newbies: this Approach is not dedicated to Windows OS as it does not Support the concept of /proc filesystem.

Cheers

Comment: if mono app runs in a background (as a spanned process) ProcessName is "mono-sgen", even if you run it as "mono myApp.exe"

Comment: The _cmdline_ output becomes more readable if `File.ReadAllText()` is continued by `.TrimEnd('\0').Split('\0')`. The content read are null terminated strings. Replaced by spaces the output becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

[getting-mono-process-info](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2014/07/23/getting-mono-process-info-from-a-mono-app/)

The solution uses the same approach of reading /proc but has more options.

Cheers