# How to kill Linux properly C#

Tags: c#, linux, process

I need an app to quickly kill all programs launched, so far I've tried this and none of it kills any of these processes:

```
    static string[] helpers = new string[] { "/home/user1/server/server.exe", "/home/user1/server/MarginGenerator.exe", "/home/user1/server/nextday/NextDayTicketSystem.exe" };
    static string[] helpers_apps = new string[] { "server", "MarginGenerator", "NextDayTicketSystem" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(string s in helpers)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(s))
            {
                process.Kill();
                Console.WriteLine("Killing: " + s);
            }
        }
        foreach (string s in helpers_apps)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(s))
            {
                process.Kill();
                Console.WriteLine("Killing: " + s);
            }
        }
        foreach (string s in helpers_apps)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(s))
            {
                Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

                foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
                {

                    if (theprocess.ProcessName.StartsWith(s))
                        theprocess.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (string s in helpers_apps)
        {
            Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName.ToLower()
                                     .StartsWith(s))
                                     .ToList()
                                     .ForEach(x => x.Kill());

                Console.WriteLine("Killing: " + s);
        }
    }
```

I launch this app using command:
sudo /home/user1/server/AppsKiller.exe

Comment: If you just list the processes, are the names you are comparing against in the list?

Comment: foreach(Process s in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            } doesn't show any of these running apps, but when i run glances, these processes are there, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Process.Kill() is not a recommended way of stopping a process. It effectively sends the SIGKILL signal which unceremoniously terminates the process. By using the `pkill` command with just the process name or `kill` command with the PID (process identifier) you will politely ask the process in question to stop by sending it the SIGTERM signal. For more information on SIGTERM and SIGKILL please see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html.

In short for your use case a good option is to do the following.

```
 Process.Start("/bin/bash", " -c 'sudo pkill -f process_name'");
```

It will nicely ask the process to stop. If the process doesn't end, you can then resort to using:
     Process.Kill();

Comment: ```Process.Start("pkill", $"-f {process_name}");``` should be enough if the processs that needs to be killed is run by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

This answer ([Get process executed by MONO on GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374761/get-process-executed-by-mono-on-gnu-linux)) suggests that if the processes you are trying to list are Mono processes, then their process name will be 'Mono' and you'll need to look at the command line to see what is really going on.